# How to get a property value from model in OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm working on an `Asp.Net core 5` project targeted `.Net 5`,

In many cases in views I used `select` lists and selected value from the list will be affected to one of `model` `properties`.

I'm familiar with `Action filters` but beginner in my level, so I tried to create a custom filter that will check if any `property`'s value in the `model` equal `default_option`I will add an error `model state`, all this code should happen in `OnActionExecuting` method.

**What I tried :**

```
public class CheckDefaultOptionFromSelect : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext context )
        {
            var model = ( (Controller) context.Controller ).ViewData.Model;

            if ( model is not null )
            {
                foreach ( var property in model.GetType().GetProperties() )
                {

                        if ( (string) model.GetType().GetProperty( property.Name ).GetValue( model ).ToString() == "default_option" )
                        {
                            context.ModelState.AddModelError( "" , "Please select an option" );

                            base.OnActionExecuting( context );
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**In those actions views will have this piece:**

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                    <select asp-for="PropertyName" asp-items="@(new SelectList(myCollection,"Id","Title") )" class="form-select form-control form-control-lg form-control-outlined" data-ui="lg" data-search="on">
                                        <option value="default_option">Default Option</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <label asp-for="PropertyName" class="form-label-outlined"></label>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="PropertyName" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**the most important piece is that:**

```html
                                    <select asp-for="PropertyName" asp-items="@(new SelectList(myCollection,"Id","Title") )" class="form-select form-control form-control-lg form-control-outlined" data-ui="lg" data-search="on">
                                        <option value="default_option">Default Option</option>
                                    </select>
```

**The problem :**
When I debug using `break points` I saw that the `( (Controller) context.Controller ).ViewData.Model` always `null`.

**The Question:**
Please how can I iterate for all `model` properties and check values if not equal `default_option` ?

Comment: I believe that the model is bound via the arguments and not synced by anyway with the `ViewData.Model` at least at the phase before executing the action. Because it's bounded to all action's arguments, you need to be more specific about the actions applied by the filter (or at least show the required signature of the applied actions). You will get the arguments from `context.ActionArguments`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get the model data like below:

```
public class CheckDefaultOptionFromSelect : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("model", out object model);

        if (model is not null)
        {
            foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if ((string)model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(model).ToString() == "default_option")
                {
                    context.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please select an option");
                    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whole testing code:

Model:

```
public class Test2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

**Note**: Because you add the modelstate with empty key, so `asp-validation-for="PropertyName"` will not display the error. Be sure add `<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>` to display all the model error.

```
@model TestViewModel 
@{ 
    var myCollection = new List<Test2>()
    {
        new Test2(){ Id=1,Title="aaa"},
        new Test2(){Id=2,Title="bbb"},
        new Test2(){Id=3,Title="ccc"}
    };
}
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group"> 

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div> 

            <div class="form-control-wrap">
                <select asp-for="PropertyName" asp-items="@(new SelectList(myCollection,"Id","Title") )" class="form-select form-control form-control-lg form-control-outlined" data-ui="lg" data-search="on">
                    <option value="default_option">Default Option</option>
                </select>
                <label asp-for="PropertyName" class="form-label-outlined"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="PropertyName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input value="Create" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CheckDefaultOptionFromSelect))]

public IActionResult Index(TestViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Register `ActionFilterAttribute` in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<CheckDefaultOptionFromSelect>();
```

Comment: Oh, really I appreciate this for you, that's works massive thanks and god save you